# Send JSON object from Android to Elasticsearch

Tags: android, elasticsearch

I want to send a JSON object, named `feedbackQAJsonObjOuter`,  from Android App to Elasticsearch. The name of my Index in Elasticsearch is "`trial_feedback_index2`" and that of my Type is "`trial_feedback_type2`".

I set the post URL as this in my Android code, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
"http://localhost:9200/trial_feedback_index2/trial_feedback_type2 -d " + "'" + feedbackQAJsonObjOuter+ "'";
```

How do I do this using post request from Android Studio?

Comment: You are using localhost in your url.Is there any service or server app is running or you need to check the correct url

Comment: It throws any exception.Provide the exception details then it is easy to find the solution